# Debug messages with Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

What's the quickest way to print "debug" messages from Flex?  You know, things like "got a mouse click at ($x, $y)" or "received and event from $sender".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
trace(mouseEvent.x + ", " + mouseEvent.y);
```

prints it to the console if you're using Eclipse/Flex Builder.

Answer (score 3):

Using trace() is a simple way to see messages in the Flex Builder console.  But you have to run in debug mode to see them.  You can also get trace statements to print to a local file.  For more complex logging there is a Log4J-like framework in the Flex SDK.  More information on all of this is in the Flex Documentation:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=logging_07.html

Answer (score 1):

trace(`somestring`)